# How do I return a value from a callout method to a trigger so that I may validate field values against a web service?

Tags: trigger, callout

I'm trying to validate a particular field on insert or update against a web service. Before the record is saved, the data is sent over to the web service, and it returns a `Boolean` indicating whether the input is valid.

I started by writing some APEX code, but received an error indicating that callouts cannot be done from inside a trigger. With a bit of research, I found recommendations to move the callout logic into a separate class, add the `@future (callout=true)` annotation, and call it from the trigger.

Now, however, I am receiving yet another error indicating that `Future` methods cannot return a value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform web-service validation in a trigger, which means you cannot do real-time validation in this fashion nor stop the transaction from being committed based on web service results.

Future methods execute in a separate, asynchronous transaction, from which you cannot return values. The same is true of other types of asynchronous Apex, such as Queueables and Batches - they cannot synchronously return values to the code that initiated their action.

You could potentially perform this type of validation in a custom user-interface layer, whether in Visualforce or in Lightning, prior to actually initiating the save operation. Alternately, you could perform the validation asynchronously and surface an error through some other method, such as sending an email or marking a status value on the record, but would not be able to show the user an error during their save operation.

Comment: Agreed. What you really need to think about is, what is the user experience you are hoping for? That could inform which alternative you go with.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to fully recreate the page UI. I am intending to deploy this in Lightning, so what would be the best approach? Is it possible to create some kind of overlay/modal, or would the only option be to create a full-fledged custom component?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom component at some level, for sure. It might not need to replace the entire page - it could be an element, or a component action to edit only a few fields - but I can't be more specific than that without really understanding your use case in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You are right here as you cannot perform a DML operation and then make a callout real time in the same transaction. That's a [platform limitation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm).

> You can’t make a callout when there are pending operations in the same transaction. Things that result in pending operations are DML statements, asynchronous Apex (such as future methods and batch Apex jobs), scheduled Apex, or sending email. You can make callouts before performing these types of operations.

That also means:

> Synchronous Web service callouts are not supported from scheduled Apex. To be able to make callouts, make an asynchronous callout by placing the callout in a method annotated with @future(callout=true) and call this method from scheduled Apex

And with the fact that future methods do not return any values (and that's correct because they execute asynchronously), the only option you have is to design  a way where you can communicate asynchronously - say updating a record or publishing an event. And then utilize those values to process your further operations.

You just don't have a way to do things real-time/synchrnously.